# Parser example isn't clicking with me

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm reading through Real World Haskell, and as an intro into functors/monads, it gives the following example:

```
parseByte :: Parse Word8
parseByte =
    getState ==> \initState ->
    case L.uncons (string initState) of
      Nothing ->
          bail "no more input"
      Just (byte,remainder) ->
          putState newState ==> \_ ->
          identity byte
        where newState = initState { string = remainder,
                                     offset = newOffset }
              newOffset = offset initState + 1
```

(The rest of it can be read about a quarter of the way down the page at: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html)

The thing that doesn't make any sense to me is, why does this function not take any parameters? I'd expect it to accept a Parse object containing the text to be parsed, then return the parsed text, and a new Parse object. Instead, (as I see it) it's "magically" accessing a Parser, popping a byte, then returning a "modified" Parser. Where does the object come from? I've been staring at at for a day now and still have no clue how this function works.

Any guidance here would be appreciated.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state, which I found to be a more approachable explanation of how the state monad works.  The `Parse` monad used here is nothing more than the `State` monad with error handling in the form of `Either String`.  The `State` monad is nothing more than composing functions that return tuples where one of the tuple elements is always your new state.  It isn't magic, just functions being composed in a particular way.

Comment: I'm re-reading the link, and it already makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Parse` type is defined as

```
newtype Parse a = Parse
    { runParse :: ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
    }
```

So if you're wondering where the input comes from, it's in the definition of the type!  Each `Parse` value wraps up a function, and then we use `==>` in this example to chain two `Parse`s together through composition into a new `Parse`.  This is then finally run using `runParse`.  This function requires a `ParseState`, being defined as

```
data ParseState = ParseState
    { string :: L.ByteString
    , offset :: Int64
    } deriving (Show)
```

this is what carries the string being parsed.

You can think of the `Parse` type as an alias for the type

```
ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
```

which is a function like you'd expect.  With the `==>` function having the type (with the newtype wrapper removed)

```
(==>)
    ::       (ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState))
    -> (a -> (ParseState -> Either String (b, ParseState)))
    ->       (ParseState -> Either String (b, ParseState))
```

we can then take one `Parse` and feed it into another `Parse` to make a new `Parse`.  All of this is no more than a fancy wrapper around regular function composition.  It gets it input from where-ever `runParse` is called from the initial state.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this still doesn't make sense. Are you saying that because Parse is essentially an alias for a function, the parseByte function actually does take a parameter, but the fact that it does is just hidden behind the alias?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, exactly.  The `Parse` type hides the fact that it's a function, and the `==>` operator is "fancy composition", which handles breaking apart the tuple, updating the state, and doing the error handling with the `Either String` bit.

Comment: Isn't (==>) the same as (>>=)? Why are they separate?

Comment: @PyRulez It appears that in RWH, there is an attempt to show the monad pattern by implementing it specifically for different types before moving to re-implement them under the common typeclass of `Monad` in chapter 14 to show how powerful it is for cleaning up code.

Comment: @bheklilr So, it's only actually a function after its been "extracted". `==>`'s job is to unwrap 2 parses compose them, then re-wrap them into a new Parse. And, I'm I right in thinking that on a individual Parser level, I shouldn't be thinking about the individual data, but how the data is processed after all the parsers are composed? Sorry if I restated anything you said. I'd just like to know that my understanding is on the right track.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That looks generally correct.  The key concept to grasp is the unwrapping, composition, and wrapping of two `Parse`s by `==>`.  This is the fundamental operation on a `Parse` object, and is central to turning this type into a `Monad` in chapter 14.  Once it's a `Monad`, Haskell has special syntax that makes composing different `Parse`s much cleaner and easier to read, so you have that to look forward to.  You could even probably skip to Ch14 if you wanted to see how it all gets tied together.

Comment: I actually understand simple Monad instances, like the List Monad and the Maybe Monad, but for some reason this wouldn't click. I'm actually reading RWH because I didn't like some of LYAHFGG's coverage of more complicated topics. His causal style introduces simple things well, but I found he tends to skip over important details in the last couple of chapters.